# In pandas, how to infer date typed columns with a custom format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to parse a csv file using pandas, with read_csv, and I am running into an issue where dates are not properly parsed, since they are in the format "%d.%m.%Y" (example : 22.01.2022)
I understand a custom date parser is needed, so I passed one in input, such as here:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(p, skiprows=[0,1,2,4], keep_default_na=False,
date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y").date(),
sep="\t"
)
```

This data extraction doesn't parse the dates as expected.

If I pass the list of columns that I expect to have dates in it, then those columns are properly parsed as dates, so I assume my custom date parser works:

```py
data = pd.read_csv(p, skiprows=[0,1,2,4], keep_default_na=False,
date_parser=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y").date(),
parse_dates=['date1', 'date2'],
sep="\t"
)
```

But I would like to avoid having to manually specify which columns pandas should be trying to parse as date columns, since the data source could evolve. I would like to have pandas guess which columns contain dates, like it does when the dates match a more standard format.

Comment: "I would like to have pandas guess which columns contain dates, **like it does when the dates match a more standard format**." - except it doesn't do that...

Comment: Maybe I assumed pandas was not parsing the dates because they weren't a more standard format. it is parsing the non-standard decimal values when I specify the thousands=' ', decimal=',' so I assumed the same should be happening for the dates.

Comment: Nope - you either set parse_dates to True in which case it does the index column, otherwise you explicitly specify which columns to try to parse dates for... trying to work out if something's a number or not is a lot easier than if it's a valid date or not - so it doesn't try and guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the pandas behaviour I was looking for turned out to not exist, here is the solution that I went with, which involves building the dataframe, and then turning the appropriate columns to date.

First I find the columns where the string data matches my format, and then apply the type:

```py
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if df[col].astype(str).str.contains(r'^\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}$', case=True, regex=True).any()]
for col in date_cols:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col],format='%d.%m.%Y')
```